# Get n numbers from array starting from given point

Tags: javascript, math

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code

```
var list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
function get_next_num(point, direction, count){
  var results = []; 
  for(i = point; i < count; i++){
      if(direction == 'left'){
          i = -i;
      }

      if(i > list.length - 1)
          i = 0;

      if(i < 0)
          i = list.length - 1;      

      results.push(i);
  }

  return results;
}
```

It's supposed to return a list of numbers from the array that start from the given point, but it only works if I start from 0.

If I start from 6 for example I get nothing

alert(get_next_num(6, 'right', 3));

but it should return 7, 0, 1

Comment: For starters, if direction is left, you toggle the minus on every iteration. And really, all you want to do is use [Array.prototype.silce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: You're pushing `i` instead of `list[i]`. Also, you start at `point` and go on to `count`. If `point` is `5` and `count` is `4`, you won't get any results. Either do `for (i = point; i < point + count; i++)` or do `for (i = 0; i < count; i++) { ... list[point + i] ... }`.

Comment: do you really want to get `7, 0, 1` from `get_next_num(6, 'right', 3));`? if you take 6 as index for the list, than you get `6`, instead of `7`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution starts from `list[point]`:

```js
var list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function get_next_num(point, direction, count) {
    var results = [],
        dir = direction === 'left' ? -1 : 1,     // used as a factor for the index
        i, index;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {                // simple count up, no hassle
        index = (point + i * dir) % list.length; // calculate the index
        if (index < 0) {                         // and respect boundaries
            index += list.length;                // add length to get a positive number
        }
        results.push(index);                     // push the value
    }
    return results;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(get_next_num(6, 'right', 3), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(get_next_num(2, 'left', 8), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

This solution starts

- for `direction = 'right'` from `list[point + 1]`
- for `direction = 'left'` from `list[point - 1]`

```js
var list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function get_next_num(point, direction, count) {
    var results = [],
        dir = direction === 'left' ? -1 : 1,     // used as a factor for the index
        i, index;
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {               // simple count up, no hassle
        index = (point + i * dir) % list.length; // calculate the index
        if (index < 0) {                         // and respect boundaries
            index += list.length;                // add length to get a positive number
        }
        results.push(index);                     // push the value
    }
    return results;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(get_next_num(6, 'right', 3), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(get_next_num(2, 'left', 8), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the for loop wrong. You should start `i` by `0`, not `point`. If you start by `point`, say in your example, `i=6`, condition for a loop to run is `i<count`, which means `6<3` which is wrong, so the loop never got started.

It should by like this :

```
function get_next_num(point, direction, count){
  var results = []; 
  j = 1;
  index = point
  if(direction == 'left'){
          j = -1;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
      index = index + j;
      if(index > list.length - 1)
          index = 0;

      if(index < 0)
          index = list.length - 1;      

      results.push(list[index]);
  }

  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_ex_num(point,direction,count){
    var results=[];
    if(direction=='right'&&point<count)return'error';
    else if(count<point)return'error';

    for(i=point;i<count;((direction=='right')?i++:i--)){//might case error but hey ho you get the idea and worth a try :p
        results.push(list[i]);
    }
    return results;
}
```

I haven't tested anything I'll leave that to you ;)

You're issue is when you're misusing `i` when direction is left. This doesn't change the direction it just changes what `i` is. the direction is determined by `++` and or `--`.

I've made it so when direction is left. count must be lower than point to run. And when direction is right count must be higher than point.

You can use this function like this.

```
norm=get_ex_num(0,'left',7);
backwards=get_ex_num(7,'right',6);
error=get_ex_num(4,'left',5);
error2=get_ex_num(5,'right',4);
```

If I've made a mistake go way on me I've been working on wordpress plugins for about 7 hours with a cold today DX

Also Another reason you code doesn't work is `i` is just an index. It's not `list`'s key value.

If I've made a mistake it's probably because of `list[i]`.

Check this out if it doesn't work :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf